# As características funcionais do Java 8 tornaram algum design pattern obsoleto?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern, java-8, programação-funcional

Diz-se que programação funcional torna certos padrões de projeto (pensando no GoF) desnecessários. Tem até uma apresentação mostrando isso em algum lugar (não procuro agora porque estou no celular).

As características funcionais do Java 8 chegaram a tornar algum design pattern obsoleto?

Comment: Cara, eu tenho a impressão que vem pra ajudar, na real. 
Se você pensar, por exemplo, no Optional<T>, me parece que ele vai facilitar algumas patterns de validações, como o Chains of Responsability.
Nesse caso, podemos usar o orElse(...) pra realizar o encadeamento, por exemplo.

Comment: Na real, eu acho que qdo a gente passa pra patterns organizacionais(é esse o termo?) o Java 8 pode quebrar um pouco. Pensando nas do GoF, eu acho que no máximo ele simplifica, saca?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depois do Java 8, se vê com frequência essa polêmica sobre dizer que alguns patterns clássicos se tornaram obsoletos. Um pattern codifica o que se considera como melhor prática para um tipo de problema, mas nem toda prática é eternamente a melhor e pode ser substituída ou constantemente aperfeiçoada. Continua sendo importante conhecer os problemas que cada pattern se propõe a resolver, mesmo que uma melhoria na implementação seja possível.

A própria *Gang of Four* considera que a linguagem de programação escolhida influencia em como o pattern vai ser implementado, sendo mais fácil ou mais difícil dependendo dos recursos que a linguagem oferece: "*In fact, there are enough differences between Smalltalk and C++ to mean that some patterns can be expressed more easily in one language than the other. (See Iterator for example.)*"

O livro *Java 8 Lambdas: Pragmatic Functional Programming* descreve alguns patterns **melhorados** pelo Java 8. Por exemplo, o pattern **Observer**, em casos mais simples, pode dispensar a implementação das classes que implementam a interface que define um observador. Estas classes são substituídas por funções do Java 8. O pattern foi simplificado bastante, mas o problema continua existindo e o pattern também.

Para ilustrar a simplificação no pattern Observer, considere a seguinte interface a ser implementada por organizações que desejem observar quem pousa na lua. Neste exemplo, aliens e a Nasa serão observadores.

```
public interface LandingObserver {
  public void observeLanding(String name);
}
```

O sujeito é a Lua:

```
public class Moon {
  private final List<LandingObserver> observers = new ArrayList<>();

  public void land(String name) {
    for(LandingObserver observer : observers) {
      observer.observeLanding(name);
    }
  }

  public void startSpying(LandingObserver observer) {
    observers.add(observer);
  }
}
```

A seguir, estão as implementações dos observadores que representam os aliens e a Nasa e que respondem ao evento de um pouso na lua.

Aliens:

```
public class Aliens implements LandingObserver {
  @Override
  public void observeLanding(String name) {
    if(name.contains("Apollo")) {
      System.out.println("They're distracted, lets invade earth!");
    }
  }
}
```

Nasa:

```
public class Nasa implements LandingObserver {
  @Override
  public void observeLanding(String name) {
    if(name.contains("Apollo")) {
      System.out.println("We made it!");
    }
  }
}
```

O código do cliente, usualmente é, por exemplo:

```
Moon moon = new Moon();
moon.startSpying(new Nasa());
moon.startSpying(new Aliens());

moon.land("An asteroid");
moon.land("Apollo 11");
```

Usando lambdas, as classes Aliens e Nasa, mostradas anteriormente, são desnecessárias. Neste caso, o cliente é algo como:

```
Moon moon = new Moon();
moon.startSpying(name -> {
  if(name.contains("Apollo"))
    System.out.println("We made it!");
});

moon.startSpying(name -> {
  if(name.contains("Apollo"))
    System.out.println("They're distracted, lets invade earth!");
});

moon.land("An asteroid");
moon.land("Apollo 11");
```